# in google cloud storage do you pay the early termination fee for overwriting objects with object versioning enabled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-billing

If I have object 'a' in bucket 'b' which is stored with coldline storage, with object versioning enabled, and I overwrite it before 90 days, creating a new version, do I get charged the coldline early termination fee for the original version ?

Comment: I guess stackoverflow isn&#39;t the right place for this question... How about the GCP forum...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: This is not a "customer service" question. This is a lack of understanding over documented behavior. We do know the answer, because it's documented. It's just as on topic as someone wondering how a REST endpoint works. The answer is correct and should be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Archived object versions are, for purposes of storage billing, still regular objects. The older version of your object is still available and is being stored, and you should not be charged an early deletion fee for it unless you permanently delete it before the 90 days are up. The new version is brand new and has its own, separate 90 day counter.

For this reason, if you plan on frequently overwriting objects, nearline and coldline may not be the right storage class option for you.